# Using TMP_InputField in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want text on my 3d dialog's input field to be editable (I'm using latest stable Unity, with C#). The text is using TextMesh Pro Text, and I've added a TextMesh Pro Input Field to the component, which I'm successfully calling ActivateInputField() on when it's clicked. However, no text appears when one now types on the keyboard. (Not in Editor or Build, and independent of whether I've associated the TextMesh Pro Input Field component's Text ViewPort, Text Component and Font Assets.) When I manually enter text into e.g. the Input Field component's inspector box, it does show up fine.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what this component is meant to do? How can I fix this? Thanks!

PS: My dialog is fully 3d, i.e. it's meant to be rotatable, not a UI on a 2d screen canvas.

Comment: I believe you can only use this within a canvas (so 2d only). TextMeshPro does support 3D Text meshes (Create -> 3D Object -> Text - TextMeshPro). If you want to use this in 3d, I would suggest that you use it and write your own "InputField"

Comment: Thanks. That's sad. Will go about adding my own now (I have some older code that does this).

Comment: Why is your UI in 3D anyway? It looks 2D to me (also, Canvas supports World Space, which ends up 3D, even if all of its elements are 2D).

Comment: Good question. It's in 3d mainly because I want to remain cross-compatible with a future Virtual Reality port. In such, the surface is on a virtual (3d grabbable, rotatable etc.) screen, and can be clicked with a virtual finger. You can see a video of my older project with that approach at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQa_mNRa_mw This is the main reason, but one can also tap into side benefits, e.g. in the latest version I'm using a slightly 3d-tilted display even on flatscreens (but it's unlikely I would have taken the efforts for that minor visual effect alone).

Comment: "also, Canvas supports World Space, which ends up 3D, even if all of its elements are 2D" That's interesting, thanks. Would that mean I could project the canvas onto a 3d surface that can then be tilted in relation to the camera, but also clicked on with a VR hand etc.?

Comment: Looks like the tilting itself can be done using the World Space render mode of a Canvas. Not sure it's otherwise fully compatible to all I'm doing, but I've already finished setting up my widgets now, including the text input. Thanks in any case, I'll try have a look at UI Canvas in the future, too!

Comment: PS: For reference, here you can see how my VirtualOS UI mixes 2d and 3d objects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQa_mNRa_mw&feature=youtu.be&t=122